# Why Asterisk answered "Bad Event" to PUBLISH Event: capability-change?

Tags: asterisk

I'm trying to bind Asterisk 11 and GoIP 32 Easy Phone  with sip trunk.

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  Asterisk
YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY GoIP


<--- SIP read from UDP:YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:5106 --->
     PUBLISH sip:goip-1@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX SIP/2.0
     Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.100:5106;branch=z9hG4bK1758989526
     From: sip:goip-1@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;tag=1774677406
     To: sip:goip-1@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
     CSeq: 41 PUBLISH
     Event: capability-change


    <--- Transmitting (NAT) to YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:5106 --->
    SIP/2.0 489 Bad Event
    Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.2.100:5106;branch=z9hG4bK1758989526;received=185.66.87.244;rport=5106
    From: sip:goip-1@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;tag=1774677406
    To: sip:goip-1@8XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;tag=as147ef74c
    Call-ID: 774522878@192.168.2.100
    CSeq: 41 PUBLISH
    Server: Asterisk PBX 11.25.3
    Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
```

Why Asterisk answered "Bad Event" to PUBLISH  Event: capability-change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it does not support this event type, at least not in default configuration.